# How to make a input type="file" field in a web page that is guaranteed to work in Android?

Tags: javascript, android, html, file-upload

I have a simple `<input type="file">` in a web form (to be viewed in a browser) and I need it to work on Android (besides other mobile devices and desktop).

Due to a well known but still unfixed bug in Android (https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=53088), any such input field may miserably fail to work, because while you are choosing for the file to upload (with whatever application, e.g. the Gallery or a third party file browser), the browser activity is in the background and the system may kill it at any time (no matter how huge your RAM is), and hence the page may reload when the browser activity is restored, and the file you've selected will be forgotten.
This still happens in Chrome on Android 4.4.4.
Of course it does work at times, but not always, and it's unpredictable.

I can think of (painful to implement) workarounds for a webview within a native app, but I can't think of any workaround in pure html+javascript for a web page to be visited by a browser.

The thing is, some workaround must exist, because there are web pages out there with file uploads that never occur into this issue, such as m.facebook.com to name only one. **EDIT:** forget this paragraph, facebook and twitter are affected as much as every other web page with uploads (and btw, Instagram's mobile web page does not allow upload at all, funny huh?)

Does anyone know what the working workaround is? Or if any exists at all?

Just to be clear, I need a workaround that can be applied by just adjusting the html and/or adding no-matter-how-much javascript code, but without forcing the user to install any specific extra app.

Answer (score 1):

"interesting" problem...

It is not a ready-to-use solution, but you could save the state of the page before requesting a file: 
[http://www.html5rocks.com/en/features/storage](http://www.html5rocks.com/fr/features/storage)

Comment: That would allow me to restore the state of the page, but I can't see how that can allow me to get and attach the selected file. Unless there's some API in Chrome to access the data that has been passed to the browser activity as a result from an intent (but even in that case, I don't think you would be able to set it as the attached file)

Comment: Are you sure of that? I have made a test with a page with just a file input, there was no refresh.

Comment: I have read the discussion about this issue, and it seems a too big bug to me if even the file selected is not set in the input.

Comment: But if it is really that, you are right, local storage will not be able to attach the selected file, because the problem is not at the level of the web page.

Comment: not surprised you couldn't reproduce it, it's not systematic; and yes, it _is_ too big a bug, and it's unbelievable it's being ignored by google, but that's the case.